# Running Multiple Queries in Spark Structured Streaming with Watermarking and Windowed Aggregations

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

My aim is to read data from multiple Kafka topics, aggregate the data and write into hdfs. 
I looped through the list of kafka topics to create multiple queries. The code runs fine while running a single query but gives error while running multiple queries. I've kept the checkpoint directories for all topics different as I read in many posts that this can cause a similar issue.

The code is as follows:

```
object CombinedDcAggStreaming {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {


    val jobConfigFile = "configPath"

    /* Read input configuration */
    val jobProps = Util.loadProperties(jobConfigFile).asScala

    val sparkConfigFile = jobProps.getOrElse("spark_config_file", throw new RuntimeException("Can't find spark property file"))
    val kafkaConfigFile = jobProps.getOrElse("kafka_config_file", throw new RuntimeException("Can't find kafka property file"))

    val sparkProps = Util.loadProperties(sparkConfigFile).asScala
    val kafkaProps = Util.loadProperties(kafkaConfigFile).asScala

    val topicList = Seq("topic_1", "topic_2")
    val avroSchemaFile = jobProps.getOrElse("schema_file", throw new RuntimeException("Can't find schema file..."))
    val checkpointLocation = jobProps.getOrElse("checkpoint_location", throw new RuntimeException("Can't find check point directory..."))
    val triggerInterval = jobProps.getOrElse("triggerInterval", throw new RuntimeException("Can't find trigger interval..."))
    val outputPath = jobProps.getOrElse("output_path", throw new RuntimeException("Can't find output directory..."))
    val outputFormat = jobProps.getOrElse("output_format", throw new RuntimeException("Can't find output format...")) //"parquet"
    val outputMode = jobProps.getOrElse("output_mode", throw new RuntimeException("Can't find output mode...")) //"append"
    val partitionByCols = jobProps.getOrElse("partition_by_columns", throw new RuntimeException("Can't find partition by columns...")).split(",").toSeq

    val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("streaming").master("local[4]").getOrCreate()
    sparkProps.foreach(prop => spark.conf.set(prop._1, prop._2))

    topicList.foreach(
      topicId => {

        kafkaProps.update("subscribe", topicId)


        val schemaPath = avroSchemaFile + "/" + topicId + ".avsc"


        val dimensionMap = ConfigUtils.getDimensionMap(jobConfig)
        val measureMap = ConfigUtils.getMeasureMap(jobConfig)

        val source= Source.fromInputStream(Util.getInputStream(schemaPath)).getLines.mkString
        val schemaParser = new Schema.Parser
        val schema = schemaParser.parse(source)
        val sqlTypeSchema = SchemaConverters.toSqlType(schema).dataType.asInstanceOf[StructType]

        val kafkaStreamData = spark
          .readStream
          .format("kafka")
          .options(kafkaProps)
          .load()

        val udfDeserialize = udf(deserialize(source), DataTypes.createStructType(sqlTypeSchema.fields))

        val transformedDeserializedData = kafkaStreamData.select("value").as(Encoders.BINARY)
          .withColumn("rows", udfDeserialize(col("value")))
          .select("rows.*")
          .withColumn("end_time", (col("end_time") / 1000).cast(LongType))
          .withColumn("timestamp", from_unixtime(col("end_time"),"yyyy-MM-dd HH").cast(TimestampType))
          .withColumn("year", from_unixtime(col("end_time"),"yyyy").cast(IntegerType))
          .withColumn("month", from_unixtime(col("end_time"),"MM").cast(IntegerType))
          .withColumn("day", from_unixtime(col("end_time"),"dd").cast(IntegerType))
          .withColumn("hour",from_unixtime(col("end_time"),"HH").cast(IntegerType))
          .withColumn("topic_id", lit(topicId))

        val groupBycols: Array[String] = dimensionMap.keys.toArray[String] ++ partitionByCols.toArray[String]
)

        val aggregatedData = AggregationUtils.aggregateDFWithWatermarking(transformedDeserializedData, groupBycols, "timestamp", "10 minutes", measureMap) //Watermarking time -> 10. minutes, window => window("timestamp", "5 minutes")

        val query = aggregatedData
          .writeStream
          .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(triggerInterval))
          .outputMode("update")
          .format("console")
          .partitionBy(partitionByCols: _*)
          .option("path", outputPath)
          .option("checkpointLocation", checkpointLocation + "//" + topicId)
          .start()
      })

    spark.streams.awaitAnyTermination()

    def deserialize(source: String): Array[Byte] => Option[Row] = (data: Array[Byte]) => {
      try {
        val parser = new Schema.Parser
        val schema = parser.parse(source)
        val recordInjection: Injection[GenericRecord, Array[Byte]] = GenericAvroCodecs.toBinary(schema)
        val record = recordInjection.invert(data).get
        val objectArray = new Array[Any](record.asInstanceOf[GenericRecord].getSchema.getFields.size)
        record.getSchema.getFields.asScala.foreach(field => {
          val fieldVal = record.get(field.pos()) match {
            case x: org.apache.avro.util.Utf8 => x.toString
            case y: Any => y
            case _ => None
          }
          objectArray(field.pos()) = fieldVal
        })
        Some(Row(objectArray: _*))
      } catch {
        case ex: Exception => {
          log.info(s"Failed to parse schema with error: ${ex.printStackTrace()}")
          None
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm getting the following error while running the job:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Race while writing batch 0
```

But the job runs normally when I run a single query instead of multiple. Any suggestions on how this issue can be solved?

Comment: I was curious, did you also resolve this by changing the output path or if you could find the way to write in the same path?

Comment: @AmitJoshi, I had to change the output path as well. I'm afraid writing to the same output path isn't possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be a late answer. But I also faced the same problem.

I was able to resolve the problem. The root cause was that both the queries were trying to write to the same base path. Thus there was an overlap of the _spark_meta information. Spark Structured Streaming maintain checkpointing, as well as _spark_metadata file to keep track of the batch being processed.

Source Spark Doc:

In order to correctly handle partial failures while maintaining exactly once semantics, the files for each batch are written out to a unique directory and then atomically appended to a metadata log. When a parquet based DataSource is initialized for reading, we first check for this log directory and use it instead of file listing when present.

Thus for now every query should be given a separate path. There is no option to configure the _spark_matadata location, unlike in checkpointing.

[Link to same type of question which I asked.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63075499/running-multiple-spark-kafka-structured-streaming-queries-in-same-spark-session)