# Running multiple Spark Kafka Structured Streaming queries in same spark session increasing the offset but showing numInputRows 0

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming-kafka

I have a Spark Structured Streaming consuming records from Kafka topic with 2 partition.

**Spark Job:** 2 queries, each consuming from 2 separate partition, running from same spark session.

```
    val df1 = session.readStream.format("kafka")
            .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafkaBootstrapServer)
            .option("assign", "{\"multi-stream1\" : [0]}")
            .option("startingOffsets", latest)
            .option("key.deserializer", classOf[StringDeserializer].getName)
            .option("value.deserializer", classOf[StringDeserializer].getName)
            .option("max.poll.records", 500)
            .option("failOnDataLoss", true)
            .load()
    val query1 = df1
            .select(col("key").cast("string"),from_json(col("value").cast("string"), schema, Map.empty[String, String]).as("data"))
            .select("key","data.*")
            .writeStream.format("parquet").option("path", path).outputMode("append")
            .option("checkpointLocation", checkpoint_dir1)
            .partitionBy("key")/*.trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("5 seconds"))*/
            .queryName("query1").start()
    
    val df2 = session.readStream.format("kafka")
            .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafkaBootstrapServer)
            .option("assign", "{\"multi-stream1\" : [1]}")
            .option("startingOffsets", latest)
            .option("key.deserializer", classOf[StringDeserializer].getName)
            .option("value.deserializer", classOf[StringDeserializer].getName)
            .option("max.poll.records", 500)
            .option("failOnDataLoss", true)
            .load()
val query2 = df2.select(col("key").cast("string"),from_json(col("value").cast("string"), schema, Map.empty[String, String]).as("data"))
            .select("key","data.*")
            .writeStream.format("parquet").option("path", path).outputMode("append")
            .option("checkpointLocation", checkpoint_dir2)
            .partitionBy("key")/*.trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("5 seconds"))*/
            .queryName("query2").start()
    session.streams.awaitAnyTermination()
```

**Problem**: every time the records are pushed in both the partition, both queries show progress, but only one of them is emitting the output. I can see the output from those query whose records are processed. For e.g., Kafka Partition 0 - records are pushed, spark will process the query1. Kafka Partition 1 - records are pushed when the query1 is busy processing, spark will show the start offset and end offset incremented, but numInputRows = 0 for query 2.

**Running env**: Local PC - Same problem. Dataproc cluster - spark-submit --packages

> org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:2.4.5 --class
> org.DifferentPartitionSparkStreaming --master yarn --deploy-mode
> cluster --num-executors 2 --driver-memory 4g --executor-cores 4
> --executor-memory 4g gs://dpl-ingestion-event/jars/stream_consumer-jar-
> with-dependencies.jar
> "{"multiple-streaming" : [0]}" latest
> "10.w.x.y:9092,10.r.s.t:9092,10.a.b.c:9092" "{"multiple-streaming" :
> [1]}" - Same problem.

Checkpoint and output path is Google Bucket.

**Logs**

```
20/07/24 19:37:27 INFO MicroBatchExecution: Streaming query made progress: {
  "id" : "e7d026f7-bf62-4a86-8697-a95a2fc893bb",
  "runId" : "21169889-6e4b-419d-b338-2d4d61999f5b",
  "name" : "reconcile",
  "timestamp" : "2020-07-24T14:06:55.002Z",
  "batchId" : 2,
  "numInputRows" : 0,
  "inputRowsPerSecond" : 0.0,
  "processedRowsPerSecond" : 0.0,
  "durationMs" : {
    "addBatch" : 3549,
    "getBatch" : 0,
    "getEndOffset" : 1,
    "queryPlanning" : 32,
    "setOffsetRange" : 1,
    "triggerExecution" : 32618,
    "walCommit" : 15821
  },
  "stateOperators" : [ ],
  "sources" : [ {
    "description" : "KafkaV2[Assign[multi-stream1-1]]",
    "startOffset" : {
      "multi-stream1" : {
        "1" : 240
      }
    },
    "endOffset" : {
      "multi-stream1" : {
        "1" : 250
      }
    },
    "numInputRows" : 0,
    "inputRowsPerSecond" : 0.0,
    "processedRowsPerSecond" : 0.0
  } ],
  "sink" : {
    "description" : "FileSink[gs://dpl-ingestion-event/demo/test/single-partition/data]"
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

I was able to resolve the problem.
The root cause was that both the queries were trying to write to the same base path. Thus there was an overlap of the _spark_meta information.
Spark Structured Streaming maintain checkpointing, as well as  _spark_metadata file to keep track of the batch being processed.

**Source Spark Doc:**

> In order to correctly handle partial failures while maintaining exactly once
> semantics, the files for each batch are written out to a unique
> directory and then atomically appended to a metadata log. When a
> parquet based DataSource is initialized for reading, we first check
> for this log directory and use it instead of file listing when
> present.

Thus for now every query should be given a separate path. There is no option to configure the _spark_matadata location, unlike in checkpointing.

Comment: what do you mean by "trying to write to same the same base path" ?
Could you please update your answer with updated code ?